# Suitescript 2.0 Get Values of a Sublist that uses a saved search

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Is it possible to get the values of a record sublist that is created by a filtered sublist view search? I have a sales order with a list of the item components and want to use that information for a button script. Not sure if sublist methods work for just standard custom record sublists or saved search sublists. I can pull the id of the sublist by using getSublists(), but that's it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run search.load function on your script and get all the data form that search.
refer to code examples:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih5lv.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you can figure out the saved search used for the sublist, you can just directly run the search via SuiteScript.